# webviewScaffold with internet connection in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

> I am trying this code in webview and works after disconnecting the
> internet and show a dialog , but when I using webviewScaffold doesn't
> work. how can I check the internet connection and show dialog after
> disconnecting the internet.

### this function works in webview, check internet() method

```
  Future<bool> checkinternet() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return Future.value(true);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }
```

### initState() code

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult connresult) {
      if (connresult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        dialogshown = true;
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              "Error",
            ),
            content: Text(
              "No Data Connection Available.",
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => internet_connection()),
                  );
                },
                child: Text("Exit."),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      } else if (connresult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
          connresult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        imageui();
        /*if (_previousResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
          checkinternet().then((result) {
            if (result == true) {
              if (dialogshown == true) {
                dialogshown = false;
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            }
          });*/
      }

      _previousResult = connresult;
    });
  }
```